# Run child processes in parallel for debugging with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to spawn child processes based on this API example: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#spawning-bat-and-cmd-files-on-windows

I simply want to run 3 commands (from NPM, like `npm run x-script`) in parallel and stream their output to the parent, but I'm
getting:

> node:events:491
>
> ```
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ```
>
> Error: spawn npm run debug-js-watch ENOENT
>
> - at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
> - at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
> - at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
>   Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
> - at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
> - at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
> - at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
>
> ```
> {
>   errno: -4058,
>   code: 'ENOENT',
>   syscall: 'spawn npm run debug-js-watch',
>   path: 'npm run debug-js-watch',
>   spawnargs: []
> }
> ```

Here's the code:

```js
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

function runInParallel(command, argumentsList) {
    let childProcess = spawn(command, argumentsList);
    childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(data.toString());
    });

    /*
    childProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
    });
    */
}

runInParallel('npm run debug-js-watch', []);
runInParallel('npm run debug-css-watch', []);
runInParallel('npm run debug-serve', []);
```

Answer (score 1):

`spawn` takes a command and an arguments list. You can fix this by splitting your string.

```
function runInParallel(cmd) {
    const [ command, ...argumentsList ] = cmd.split(' ')
    let childProcess = spawn(command, argumentsList);
    // etc

runInParallel('npm run debug-js-watch');
// etc
```

Comment: Although this makes sense, I still keep getting `ENOENT`... That, more exactly: `{
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm',
  path: 'npm',
  spawnargs: [ 'run', 'debug-js-watch' ]
}` Is not NPM supposed to exist?

Comment: Hmm, I don't get that error after the change in my answer, but I'm also not on Windows. I'm assuming `npm` is in your `%PATH%`? You may need to adjust so it's `cmd.exe /c [rest of command]`, because Windows is like that

Comment: Then the problem is the `syscall` part maybe? Anyway, I just got `exec` working instead of `spawn`. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `spawn` doesn't find `npm`. I had to use `exec` instead and it worked:

```js
const {exec} = require('node:child_process');

function runInParallel(cmd) {
    let childProcess = exec(cmd);
    ...
}
```